# Entangle masers?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-entanglement

If I point a collection of masers at an antenna, I can broadcast a signal to phase-lock them to, so that their output will interfere constructively at my antenna.

Is it possible, in principle, to not only synchronize, but entangle the masers, so that the probability amplitudes of their output interfere constructively at my antenna, *and* thereby deliver more energy to the antenna than classical E-M interference would?

Does this question even make sense? If so, what kind of boost could entangled interference deliver, in principle, over classical E-M interference?